# python chorus effect and meaning of audio data

Tags: python, audio, numpy, audio-streaming, audioeffect

Can you please explain or point the right way to think about how to implement two sound effects on the wav file.

So I read wav file and convert it to int values (in `numpy` array)

```
array([59383, 58290, 60629, ..., 52606, 51982, 56274], dtype=uint16)
```

First, I am not sure I am clear about what these values in array really represent? 
Is it right that every value is one of 65535  ( `unsigned int16` ) magnitude levels that analog output device will produce in some moment in time ?

In theory chorus effect could be achieved by following steps:

1. Make copy of original array
2. weaken this copied array ( multiplying by some `value < 1` )
3. and add this copied array to original one

In practice I don't know how to add them correctly. Should I simply add values one by one, make convolution of two arrays or interleave original array and it's modified copy.
Also chorus effect should have **arbitrary**  time **delay**  and i don't know how can i accomplish this.

How could I implement that randomness of data I am about to add ?

Comment: since you're still understanding the concepts, i'd recommend taking this question to the signal processing forum, and then come back for code details after you understand the concepts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this is not (yet) a programming problem

Comment: i will try to ask at `signal processing`, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have the right ideas.  Here are a few points:

1) The wave file is linear signal vs time, so your understanding of it is correct.  (Many audio things are logarithmic, so it not unreasonable to think it might be non-linear -- eg, LPs are encoded in a nonlinear way.)

2) If you're going to do math, first convert to `float` or `int32` so you don't overrun the limits of `int16`.

3) To offset in time, use numpy slicing.  That is, something like `new = old[1000:]+old[:-1000]`.  Note that you need to add sections of the same length together, so if you add a time shift, you can't add it to the full array because the timeshift will be shorter.

4) As for adding with "random time" you can to that with the above for a single random time.  To make the time vary continuously throughout the addition, you need to warp your original signal and that will be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It clarified something for me.